# Plugin not working for second image, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my html, there are 2 tabs once you click on a tab the other tab is hidden, while the one that is clicked on is shown, It's a normal javascript tab interface.
I have a gallery plugin, it shows the gallery of the image in the first div, but it doesn't work for the image in the second div, even after i have hidden the image in the first div and it works based on the id as `light gallery`, Please why doesn't it show the gallery of the second image and how can i solve this issue

This is my html

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
 <li id="tabs1" onclick="showStuff(this)" class="active pic-list"><a href="#all" >&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;All (35)</a></li>
              <li id="tabs2" onclick="showStuff(this)" class="pic-list"><a href="#ext" >&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Exterior (7) <i class="fa fa-hospital"  style="margin-left: 50px; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></li>

 <div id="tabs-1" class="tabContent" style="display: block;">
              <div class="row" id="lightgallery">

                          @if(isset($images))
                            @foreach ($images as $image)
                    <div class="col-md-3 col" style="margin-bottom: 15px" data-src="{{$image->filename}}">
                      <div class="img-con" id="{{$image->id}}">
                                      <a href="">
                          <img class="mb-2 uploaded-photos" src="{{$image->filename}}" alt="">
                                      </a>
                        <div class="img-select">
                          <div class="new gvs-title">
                            <span style="color: #333333;">{{$image->description}} <i class="fa fa-upload" style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;"></i> <br/></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  @endforeach
                        @endif
              </div>
                        </div>
                  <div id="tabs-2" class="tabContent">
                  <div class="row" id="lightgallery">

                      @if(isset($images))
                          @foreach ($images as $image)
                              <div class="col-md-3 col" style="margin-bottom: 15px" data-src="{{$image->filename}}">
                                  <div class="img-con" id="{{$image->id}}">
                                      <a href="">
                                          <img class="mb-2 uploaded-photos" src="{{$image->filename}}" alt="">
                                      </a>
                                      <div class="img-select">
                                          <div class="new gvs-title">
                                              <span style="color: #333333;">{{$image->description}}080808008080 <i class="fa fa-upload" style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;"></i> <br/></span>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          @endforeach
                      @endif
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

This is my jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#lightgallery').lightGallery();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by basically calling two light gallery functions and changing the id of the 2 divs i.e `lightgallery` and `lightgallery1`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#lightgallery').lightGallery();
        $('#lightgallery1').lightGallery();
    });
```

Comment: This fix you did probably helped because it isn't valid for two elements in a document to have the same `id`, even if one of them isn't visible to the user. If both of your divs have `id="lightGallery"`, then `$('#lightGallery')` will only return the first one.